# How are they blocking RDP on port 80?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, firewall, port-forwarding, blocking

I'm on a corporate computer that is behind a very restrictive firewall, and trying to connect to my home computer.
I configured my router to forward port 80 to 3389 (RDP port). My idea was to try to connect with port 80 since the regular RDP port might be blocked. 
However I found out that it's not working. RDP on port 80 is blocked as well.

My router's IP address is not blocked, since I can access the config interface on `<router IP address>:8080` . Remote Desktop itself also works for connections to hosts within the internal domain.

I was wondering how are they blocking that kind of traffic (RDP on port 80 towards external IPs)? What kind of firewall rule is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely they are using either a proxy server directly in the browser settings, or they are using a transparent proxy in the path.

A proxy server will check that valid HTTP traffic is passing through and discard anything that isn't (if only because it doesn't know how to process non-http traffic).

In either case, your work PC does not have direct access to the internet, it just appears to.

Comment: Yea they have a browser proxy for HTTP, and they block pretty much everything else. I guess this explains it, thanks.